# Arrays y Diccionarios en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, diccionarios

Estoy realizando un curso de introducción a la programación en el cual estamos usando JavaScript con la consola del navegador y me quedó claro el tema de los arrays pero el de los diccionarios para nada.

Por ejemplo, esta línea de código no la entiendo:

```
for(var i=0; i < cartas.length; i=i+1)
```

Entiendo que lo que hace es recorrer el array pero no entiendo su funcionamiento.

Este código tampoco lo comprendo:

```
for (var i = 0; i < palos.length; i = i + 1) {        
    //aca me dice que para el indice igual a 0,i < palos.length esto no lo entiendo 
    //y el i=i + 1 lo que hace es recorrer el array 

    for (var j = 1; j <= 12; j = j + 1) {
        //esta parte no la entiendo para nada

        baraja[baraja.length] = { p: palos[ i ], v: j };
        //esta parte no la entiendo para nada

    }
}
```

Por poner ejemplos, es un tema que no me ha quedado nada claro. Agradecezco si alguien puede ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la primera línea que das, `for(var i=0; i < cartas.length; i=i+1)` su funcionamiento es así: `for` es una palabra reservada del lenguaje que espera unos paréntesis en donde definirás cómo se hará el ciclo:

> a) primero recibe una **inicialización**, esto es, defines cómo comenzará el ciclo (`var i=0`, declaras una variable `i` cuyo valor será 0);
>
> b) en segundo lugar cuál es la condición para que el ciclo pare (`i<cartas.length`, esa variable `i` tiene que ser menor que la longitud del array `cartas`);
>
> c) por último recibe el *incremento* (`i=i+1` indica que cada vez que termine de hacer lo que hay dentro del bloque `for` a esa variable `i` le sumará 1).

Eso responde también la primera línea del código que pones de ejemplo pero cambiando el arreglo `cartas` por el arreglo `palos`. La siguiente:

```
for (var j = 1; j <= 12; j = j + 1)
```

Indica que inicializarás la variable `j` y le asignarás el valor `1`, repetirás el ciclo mientras `j` sea **menor o igual que** (`<=`) 12 y el aumento de `j` al finalizar la tarea será uno (`j=j+1`).

Finalmente,

```
baraja[baraja.length] = { p: palos[ i ], v: j };
```

funciona así:

> El arreglo `baraja` en la **posición** `baraja.length` (la posición en un arreglo la ubicas con los corchetes, `[]`) será un objeto cuya propiedad `p` será lo que contenga el arreglo `palos` en la posición `i`, así como su propiedad `v` será el valor actual de `j`.

Por partes:

- En JavaScript puedes definir *objetos* con sólo usar las llaves `{}`. Usando esta notación:

  ```
  {
    clave: valor
  }
  ```

  que es a lo que te refieres con los **diccionarios**. En tu ejemplo:

  ```
  {
    p: palos[i], // posiblemente "Palo"
    v: j         // posiblemente "Valor"
  }
  ```
- También en JavaScript, puedes agregarle un valor a un arreglo de varias maneras. Para el caso, lo que estás haciendo es así:

  > Si el arreglo `arr` tiene 3 posiciones (`["a", "b", "c"]`), su *length* es 3. Recuerda que sus índices (*posiciones*) empiezan en 0, por lo tanto `arr[0]` = `"a"`.
  >   Si le *asignas* un valor en una posición que no existe (por ejemplo, `arr[3]`, recuerda que su último índice es `arr[2]`) entonces lo añadirá.

  (Recuerda que la comparación es con dos `==`, incluso 3 `===`, mientras que la asignación es con solo uno `=`).

Por lo tanto, al usar el nuevo índice `baraja.length` estás creando un nuevo elemento en el arreglo, y dicho objeto será un *diccionario* con un valor para `p` y un valor para `v`.

La última magia de JavaScript: podrás acceder de dos maneras:

```
baraja[1]["p"] // "Notación Corchetes"
baraja[1].p    // "Notación Punto"
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que primeramente dices que no entiendes `for(var i=0; i < cartas.length; i=i+1)` se llama **ciclo for** es una de las sentencias que vas a encontrar en javascript que permite repetir **x** operación determinadas veces, en este caso va a comenzar donde `i=0`, va a seguir ejecutando lo que este dentro de su bloque hasta que la variable `i < cartas.length` lo que es lo mismo a haber llegado al limite de elementos almacenados en el arreglo `cartas` y la manera de garantizar que llegues a la condición de parada es incrementando el valor de la vairable **i** puedes hacerlo ya sea con `i++` o con `i = i + 1` el segundo es el de tu ejemplo.

Quiere decir que si cartas es un arreglo que tiene 10 elementos con esa sentencia ejecutaras lo que esté a continuación del bloque **for** 10 veces. Así sucede igual con los otros **for** solo que la condición de inicio varia al igual que la de parada

```
baraja[baraja.length] = { p: palos[ i ], v: j };
```

Esto quiere decir que en el arreglo baraja vas a ir añadiendo un nuevo elemento de tipo diccionario, que va a tener como clave o propiedad p el valor almacenado en la posición **i** del arreglo palos, y como clave o propiedad v el valor actual de la variable **j** usada en el ciclo.

Comment: el bucle for lo tengo claro,ahora igualmente me quedo aun mas claro,lo que no entiendo es esto: var as = { palos: "c", valos: 1 }                         
var rey = { palos: "c", valos: 12 }                        
var cartas = [as, rey]                                     
var mano = [{palo: "c", valor:3}{palo: "d", valor:5}]      
osea la mezcla y uso en conjunto de arrays y diccionarios

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente la estructura for tiene tres partes separadas por punto y coma, esas representan la inicializacion, la condicion de salida y el paso.
La linea `for( var i = 0; i < cartas.length; i+=i+1)` representa que en el siguiente bloque pasara lo siguiente:

1. Al entrar ejecutara la instruccion `var i = 0` lo cual declara la
   variable `i` en el bloque y le asigna el valor `0`.
2. Evaluara la expresion `i < cartas.length`, de modo que si resulta
   ser verdadero el bloque se iterara, pero si resulta falso entonces
   el programa saldra del bloque y continuara su ejecucion normal.
3. Y por ultimo esta el paso `i += i + 1` este se ejecutara al final de
   cada iteracion, la idea es que modifique algo, de modo que el bloque
   llegue a concretar su finalizacion. Es decir, como incrementa el
   valor de `i` en `1`, eventualmente la condicion `i < cartas.length`
   terminara por ser falsa y el bloque terminara su ejecucion.

Luego, en la parte de `baraja[baraja.length] = { p: palos[ i ], v: j };` basicamente lo que esta haciendo es agregar un elemento al array, si el array tiene `n` elementos, entonces sus indices iran desde el `0` al `n-1`, de modo que el elemento `n` sera creado cuando sea accedido **( esto es asi en javascript, pero en otros lenguajes puede causar muchos errores )**. La propiedad `baraja.length` dice cuantos son esos `n` elementos del array `baraja` y al asignarle un valor, la esta creando.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es simplemente un bucle para repetir una linea de codigo cuantas veces sea necesario , en este caso se usa para recorrer todos los espacios de tu arreglo llamado cartas

```
for(var i=0; i < cartas.length; i=i+1)
//i=0 es tu valor inicial 
//i < cartas.length es la condicion que se tiene que cumplir para que deje de hacer lo que esta dentro de los corchetes {}
//en este caso dice que la variable i tiene que ser menor al tamaño de tu arreglo cartas
//i=i+1 lo puedes reemplazar por i++ que es el numero de veces que tu variable i va a incrementar en este caso cada que NO se cumpla la condicion i < cartas.length; aumentara en uno hasta que sean iguales
```

Answer (score 0):

Complementando la explicación de Daniel aquí tienes un ejemplo para que entiendas mejor el funcionamiento del ciclo for:

```js
var palos = ["corazones", "picas", "tréboles", "diamantes"];
var numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 , 12];
for (var i = 0; i < palos.length; i++) {
for (var j = 0; j < numeros.length; j++) {
  console.log(numeros[j] + " de " + palos[i]);
    }
}
```

Es un ejemplo parecido al que has compartido, en este caso hay un ciclo for en el que la variable `i` es igual a 0, menor que el número de items del array `palos` y se va incrementando de 1 en 1, y dentro de este ciclo hay otro que funciona igual pero con el array `numeros`, y con `console.log` gracias al ciclo for se muestran todas las cartas de una hipotética baraja en muy pocas líneas de código.

Comment: el bucle for lo tengo claro,ahora igualmente me quedo aun mas claro,lo que no entiendo es esto: var as = { palos: "c", valos: 1 }                         
var rey = { palos: "c", valos: 12 }                        
var cartas = [as, rey]                                     
var mano = [{palo: "c", valor:3}{palo: "d", valor:5}]      
osea la mezcla y uso en conjunto de arrays y diccionarios